# Order by selected record in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like

```
city | pincode

abcd | 123456
xyz  | 326545
asd  | 625844
city | 999999
```

and I want the result sorted with the selected `pincode` first

If I select `pincode` is `625844` which city is `asd` it must be show first

Desired output:

```
    city | pincode

    asd  | 625844  <<-- this is selected pincode must be first
    abcd | 123456
    xyz  | 326545
    city | 999999
```

Comment: I believe that you have at least one correct answer below, so the cultural thing to do as an SOer is to mark one answer as the correct one... As soon as you get a chance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select * from tbl 
order by (case when pincode = '625844' then 0 else 1 end), pincode
```

or if the selected pincode is being passed in as a parameter @pincode, this should work

```
select * from tbl 
order by (case when pincode = @pincode then 0 else 1 end), pincode
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ORDER BY
        (pincode = @mypincode) DESC,
        pincode
```

Answer (score 1):

```
( select * from pincodes where pincode = ? )
union all
( select * from pincodes where pincode !=? order by pincode asc )
```

Use required `pincode` value as search parameter in the query.

Comment: @Quassnoi That is what OP is expecting ! Isn't it? See the `output like` in posting.

Comment: the OP expects the selected `pincode` come out first. Your query is equivalent to mere `ORDER BY pincode`.

Comment: @Quassnoi Yes. First part of my query returns the selected record of the `pincode` and the Second part of the query returns rest of the records which does not contain selected `pincode`

Comment: your query will return `123456, 326545, 625844, 999999`.

Comment: @Quassnoi Ok. I got time to fix it.

Comment: With `MySQL` (or, rather, current implementation of `MySQL`), this would work. However, it is not safe to rely on this behavior which can break between upgrades. According to SQL standard, order is only defined by the outermost `ORDER BY` (which you don't have), and in some systems, like `SQL Server`, this query would not even parse.

Answer (score 1):

```
....
ORDER BY (case when pincode = @pincode then 0 else 1 end), pincode asc
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/case-statement.html

Answer (score 0):

Assign weights to all of your zipcodes and assign min weight to the zip code you want first.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following order by statement:

```
order by (case when pincode in (<selected pin codes>) then -1
               else pincode
           end)
```

I am assuming the pincode is a positive number, and choosing -1 so it comes first.